# Узнать версию API

Tags: android

Добрый день. Как можно программно узнать версию API устройства?

Например если API > 22 выполнить одно действие, а если меньше 22 другое действие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22)
else
```