# Немогу понять причину вылета приложения на устройстве с ОС Android 4.3 (Error inflating class ImageView)

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

Возникает ошибка при запуске приложения на устройстве Galaxy S3, с Android ОС 4.3.
Как понять из-за чего она возникает? Учитывая тот факт, что на всех остальных устройствах с разными ОС в тесте, всё в порядке и всё работает.

Из LogCat я понял, что проблема в .xml представлении

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_previous.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080132`

Но что с ним не так? Содержание `selector_previous.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fast_rewind_96dp" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_96dp" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_96dp" />
</selector>
```

содержание файла `ic_fast_rewind_96dp.xml`:

```
<vector android:height="96dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="96dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M11,18L11,6l-8.5,6 8.5,6zM11.5,12l8.5,6L20,6l-8.5,6z"/>
</vector>
```

содержание файла `ic_chevron_left_96dp.xml`:

```
<vector android:height="96dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="96dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>
</vector>
```

вьюшку `selector_previous.xml` использую в `activity_main.xml` разметке, применяя к imageView:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_backward"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/selector_previous" />
```

**LogCat:**

```
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pro/com.pro.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Error inflating class ImageView
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Error inflating class ImageView
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at com.tequila.online.radio.pro.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:174)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    ... 11 more
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_previous.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080132
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2974)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:129)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:360)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
04-26 09:24:50.427: E/AndroidRuntime(13122):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDe
04-26 09:24:50.442: I/ActivityManager(2345): Notify an ApplicationCrash
04-26 09:24:50.442: W/ActivityManager(2345): Error in app com.pro running instrumentation ComponentInfo{androidx.test.tools.crawler/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}:
04-26 09:24:50.442: W/ActivityManager(2345):   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
04-26 09:24:50.442: W/ActivityManager(2345):   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
04-26 09:24:50.447: D/AndroidRuntime(13111): Shutting down VM
```

Comment: нужно включить поддержку векторной графики [через библиотеки поддержки гугла](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution) для работы с API < 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Векторные изображения, поддерживают устройства, начиная с api 21. Попробуйте использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: А объяснить это в разметке представлений можно? чтоб вьюшку не инициализировать на устройствах  с API<21

Comment: Да можно, через код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602294/Узнать-версию-api после чего, программно передаете в ImageView необходимый файл для отображения. Второй вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536079/adapt-layout-to-android-platform-or-api-level

Comment: ок, а в разметке тогда нужно убрать app:srcCompat="@drawable/..." ?

Comment: Я отредактировал коментарий. Не обязательно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: почему сторонние библиотеки? поддержка векторной графики [есть в библиотеках поддержки гугла](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution) начиная с android 2.1

Comment: @pavlofff, а почему тогда при использовании `app:srcCompat="@drawable/selector_previous"` приложение падает на устройстве с API 18 ? в build.gradle параметр так же добавлен `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`